# Does my code leak memory?

Tags: c, heap-memory, free, calloc

I have a piece of code that takes a command line argument consisting of two numbers separated by a colon (e.g. 1:8) and converts it to the corresponding integer values:

```
const char delimiter[] = ":";
int numOne = 0, numTwo = 0;
char *tmp = (char *)calloc(16, sizeof(char));

tmp = strtok(argv[i+1], delimiter);
numOne = atoi(tmp);
while (tmp != NULL) {
    numTwo = atoi(tmp);
    tmp = strtok(NULL, argv[i+1]);
}

free(tmp);
```

This code works perfectly fine, however, I learned that the atoi() function does not have any kind of error handling implemented. Thus, if a too large value is provided, the program might continue in undefined behavior.

For that reason, I would like to replace it with strtol() and have tried it like this:

```
const char delimiter[] = ":";
int numOne = 0, numTwo = 0;
char *end;
char *tmp = (char *)calloc(16, sizeof(char));

tmp = strtok(argv[i+1], delimiter);
numOne = strtol(tmp, &end, 10);
if (errno == ERANGE) {
    printf("range error\n");
}
// ...

free(tmp);
```

Now, while the strtol() function seems to work fine as long as the converted values are valid integers, I get the following error once a too large number is passed as command line parameter:

```
*** Error in `program`: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000007fefc4077b ***
```

Can anyone explain to me, please, why the free(tmp) doesn't seem to be necessary in the second version of the code? And what happens to the initially allocated memory area? Does it leak? If so, is that a problem, or can it simply be reallocated by another program as I would assume?

Comment: `strtol` should be assigned to a `long`, not an int.  If you need to convert to int afterwards, range check first.

Comment: `char *tmp = (char *)calloc(16, sizeof(char));

tmp = strtok(argv[i+1], delimiter);` leaks the memory just allocated.

Comment: In `free(tmp);`, `tmp` no longe points to [the beginning of] the memory allocated with `calloc`.

Comment: Okay ... changing the data types from int to long is no problem in the code. I can do that. As for the memory allocation, I should get rid of it? Should I simply declare char *tmp? And why? I thought it would make sense to allocate memory as I don't know how long the CL parameter is going to be (only that it has to fit in the allocated space to be valid).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Could you please elaborate on this? I don't understand why that should be the case. Is the result of strtok() not stored in the allocated memory area?

Comment: @chux Why do I not get any errors in the atoi() version of the code, despite doing the same thing: allocating and freeing?

Comment: `free(tmp);`, when `tmp` is not an value returned from `*alloc()`, is _undefined behavior_.  An "error" is not required - even when doing the "same" thing.  "I not get any errors" is more like "I not detect any errors"

Comment: Okay, thank you all. I will get rid of the memory allocation and the free, change the variable type from int to long, and use valgrind with memcheck on my program, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

strtok does not allocate anything, strok returns a pointer into the provided string. `free`ing this pointer will crash the program. Strtok works similar like this:

```
char* my_strtok(char* String, char Delim)
{
  static char* pTerminus;
  static char  TerminateChar;
  if (String==NULL) //continue search and return next token
  {
     if (pTerminus==NULL) return NULL;
     *pTerminus = TerminateChar; //Restore original string 
     String = pTerminus+1;       //Continue search right behind of last token
  }

  pTerminus = strchr(String, Delim); //Find end of token
  if (pTerminus==NULL) return String; //Final token found

  TerminateChar = *pTerminus;  //back-up delimiter
  *pTerminus='\0';             //Terminate found token
  return String;
}
```

Additionally the memory provided by the `calloc` call before is lost.